# How do I install a standalone Greasemonkey userscript into Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

Installing Greasemonkey user scripts could not be any easier, usually, but how do you install a .js file which has already been downloaded like, for example, from GitHub, or copied from pastebin?

With Google Chrome's built-in Greasemonkey support there is no apparent interface to do this, and I cannot find any suitable location in the user directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the file to `*.user.js` and drag and drop the file to Chrome. It'll prompt you if you want to proceed with the installation. The script will be converted to a Chrome extension and installed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it now says

> Extensions, apps, and user scripts can only be added from the Chrome
>   Web Store.

But you can still drag and drop user scripts or extensions onto `chrome://chrome/extensions/` page aka `Menu — Tools — Extensions`.

Comment: Chrome 81+ You must enable Developer Mode first to install scripts now.

Comment: as far as I can tell, the only way now is with Tampermonkey. (directly dragging scripts shows them in the extensions but they are disabled and cannot be enabled)